# About time costs, what is more expensive: movement or overwritting? C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, move, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let us suposse I have a stack of "unused" dynamic objects. Each time I need a new object, I use one of this "unused" objects as placeholder for the new petition. Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class my_list
{
public:
   template<typename... Args>
   T* newObject(Args&&... args)
   {
       if (unused.empty())
          return new T(forward<Args>(args)...);
       else {
          auto* newbie = unused.top();
          unused.pop();

          newbie = new (newbie) T(forward<Args>(args)...); // l. X

          return newbie;
       }
   }

private:
   stack<T*> unused;
```

};

Question is, in line X, what is more efficient, the written sentence, or:

```
*newbie = std::move(T(forward<Args>(args)...));
```

That means, what is more time-efficient of both, a call of a `new` with `newbie` as address (avoiding petitions of new memory) or simply a movement of a new temporary object overwritting the original?

Comment: Please note that constructing an object on the storage of another without ending its lifetime first isn't a great idea. You may want to add `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>(), "T must be trivially copyable")`, or fix the code and destroy the objects before you construct new ones on their storage. (Or just stop doing weird stuff and move)

Comment: Do not recycle memory unless you absolutely need to.  With desktop PCs, most applications are not executed long enough to fragment memory or worry about reusing it.  On embedded systems or systems with constrained minimal memory, you shouldn't be allocating dynamic memory in the first place.

Comment: In general, don't copy objects, pass by reference or pointer.  Most objects are not big enough to worry about the impact to performance time.  There are other bottlenecks more important than copying or moving.

Comment: @Thomas: I recommend you read the advice "Want speed? Pass by value." and the excellent article defending it.  Also, applications are often left open for a duration that would be surprising to the original developers.  Unless the application automatically exits after executing a bounded number of tasks, assume it remains running for a very long time.

Comment: It depends on now you initialized (or not) the objects pointed by the elements of `unused`, it could even be UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `move` is unnecessary, since a constructor call creates a prvalue temporary.  Your question comes down to which is more efficient:

```
newbie->~T();
new (newbie) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

or

```
*newbie = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Assuming `T` has a properly-written move assignment operator, there is likely to be little difference if any; in terms of side effects the destructor of `T` is called before the constructor in the first case, and after in the second, but there is no reason to believe that this would affect performance one way more than the other.  The latter could result in more primitive value copies, but any decent optimising compiler will eliminate them.

In the absence of performance testing indicating that the former significantly improves performance, you should prefer the latter as it is far more readable, and easier to make exception safe.

Comment: And why is easier to exception safe?

Comment: @Peregring-lk if the selected constructor of `T` throws, in the first case `newbie` is left in a destructed state, violating the invariant that elements of `unused` are constructed objects.  In the second case `newbie` is left unaltered.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another viable option.  It has the advantage that while C++11 is still required for perfect forwarding, it works with library code that hasn't been updated to implement move construction and assignment.

```
T(forward<Args>(args)...).swap(*newbie);
```

Besides, your move assignment call already has a temporary object, no need to explicitly make it movable.

```
*newbie = T(forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Either of these will make it much easier to provide exception safety than the "first destroy, then construct in-place" approach.